# sphinx autosummary: "failed to import Child.model" (inherited instance attribute)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autosummary

I'm having trouble with sphinx and autosummary. Apparently, sphinx is unable to document inherited instance attributes. For some reason, the resulting error is an import error.

python code:

```
class Base:
    """Base class."""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Init."""
        self.model = None
        """An attribute."""


class Child(Base):
    """Child class."""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Init."""
        super().__init__()
        pass
```

rst documentation file:

```
.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated

    mylib.Base
    mylib.Child
```

when I run `make html` I get the following error:

```
.../new_docs/generated/mylib.Child.rst:24: WARNING: autosummary: failed to import Child.model
```

Notice that everything else is imported correctly, so this is not a path issue.

Is it possible to resolve this problem? I'm using sphinx-build 4.3.0.

Comment: I can reproduce this. There is a problem with inherited instance attributes. A related issue about instance attributes was closed this year: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3257.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn. Do you think that this is a sphinx bug and I should open an issue on github? Your linked issue suggests that my example should work without warnings.

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9884